# Calculation of integer and a floating number

Tags: floating-point, integer, calculator

Im trying to calculate an integer and a floating number. Sounds like something easy right?

However when I execute the following code:

```
<?php
$decimals = 2;
$dec_point = ',';
$thousands_sep = '.';

$net_no = 851.12;
$net_no = number_format($net_no,$decimals,$dec_point,$thousands_sep);

$months = 13;

$tot_amount = $months * $net_no;
$tot_amount = 
number_format($tot_amount,$decimals,$dec_point,$thousands_sep);

print $tot_amount;
```

I get 11.063,00 as a result, however I would expect 11.064,56 (13*851.12).

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

in total amount try to add in number_format((float) $tot_amount....) or $precision

Comment: I did add the number_format as you can see in the line beneath '$tot_amount =' and i defined $decimals as 2, however this only puts a comma and two zeroes behind the number

Comment: how about moving net_no = 851.12 after number_format($net_no...)